# Function stubbed out with Structuremap Automocking not returning value

Tags: c#, structuremap-automocking

Using Josh Flanagans [StructureMap Automocking overview](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/joshuaflanagan/archive/2009/02/03/auto-mocking-explained.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage), I'm trying my hand at it but can get the following code to return the Category object I've assigned:

```
    [Test]
    public void Service_Should_Return_Category_From_ID()
    {
        // Arrange
        var categoryToTest = new Category()
            {
                ID = 1,
                Name = "Department 1",
                Description = "Department 1 description"
            };

            var mocks = new RhinoAutoMocker<CatalogueService>();
        mocks.Get<ICatalogueService>().Stub(c => c.GetCategory(1)).Return(categoryToTest);

        // Act
        var categoryResult = mocks.ClassUnderTest.GetCategory(1);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(categoryResult);
        Assert.AreEqual(categoryToTest.ID, categoryResult.ID);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you testing here, that the stub and mocking framework works? It seems to me that you're just calling the very method you stubbed out, and verifying that it returns the same category you just said it should return. A more proper test would be to test some logic inbetween, that needs to retrieve a category, and verify that this logic works. Or... what am I missing? Because I'm pretty sure that the frameworks you're using has numerous unit tests to verify that they indeed works so you shouldn't have to duplicate that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I was adding the return value to the Interface of the class under test, not the Interface that was being Injected.